# My code in Ruby runs but does not produce output

Tags: ruby, function

I have made a simple calculator code that runs but it will not return the sum the end user is looking for.

My code is:

```
def calculator(num1,num2)
  puts"Enter you first number"
  num1 = gets.chomp

  puts " Enter operator"
  opp = gets.chomp.to_f

  puts"enter your second number \u{2753}"

  num2 = gets.chomp.to_f
  
  if opp == "+"
    puts"num1+num2"
  
  elsif opp =="-"
    puts "num1- num2"
  
  elsif opp == "/"
    puts"num1/num2"
  
  elsif opp == "*"
    puts"num1*num2"
  
  elsif opp == "%"
    puts"num1%num2"
  
  else
    puts"Wrong operator"
    
  puts"Your Result is #{calculator(num1,num2)}"
end
```

Comment: "a simple calactor code that runs" That is improbable. There are lots of syntax errors  and Ruby will tell you so.

Comment: You know you're calling your method recursively if it hits `else`, right?

Answer (score 2):

There are many other issues with this code, but the primary issue preventing output at all is that you are missing an end to your if/else conditional.

```
def calculator(num1,num2)
  puts"Enter you first number"
  num1 = gets.chomp

  puts " Enter operator"
  opp = gets.chomp.to_f

  puts"enter your second number \u{2753}"

  num2 = gets.chomp.to_f
  
  if opp == "+"
    puts"num1+num2"
  
  elsif opp =="-"
    puts "num1- num2"
  
  elsif opp == "/"
    puts"num1/num2"
  
  elsif opp == "*"
    puts"num1*num2"
  
  elsif opp == "%"
    puts"num1%num2"
  
  else
    puts"Wrong operator"
  end

  puts"Your Result is #{calculator(num1,num2)}"
end
```

Another major issue is that you're recursively calling the calculator method within the calculator method, causing recursion. I'm not sure exactly what output you're expecting but you might do something like this:

```
def calculator(num1, num2)
  puts "Enter your first number"
  num1 = gets.chomp.to_f

  puts "Enter operator"
  opp = gets.chomp

  puts "Enter your second number"
  num2 = gets.chomp.to_f
  
  case opp
  when "+"
    result = num1 + num2
    puts "Result: #{result}"
  when "-"
    result = num1 - num2
    puts "Result: #{result}"
  when "/"
    result = num1 / num2
    puts "Result: #{result}"
  when "*"
    result = num1 * num2
    puts "Result: #{result}"
  when "%"
    result = num1 % num2
    puts "Result: #{result}"
  else
    puts "Wrong operator"
  end
end

calculator(0, 0)
```

Comment: Note that the case statement could be replaced with `if ['+', '-', '*', '/', '%'].include?(opp); puts "Result: #{num1.public_send(opp, num2)}"; else; puts "Wrong operator"; end`.